# Programmatically save the HTML from internet explorer

Tags: python, html

is there a programmatical way (preferably in Python) to save the HTML source code from Internet Explorer webpage in Windows? I tried this with Python's urllib2.urlopen but I got 404 error. But I can open the link with internet explorer without 404. I think I can open the link in IE using python's Webbrowser module, but Webbrowser does not have a way to save the HTML from IE.

Comment: post the url you tried to save

Answer (score 0):

```
import urllib
from lxml import html

url = "http://yourWebsite.com/index.html"
page = html.fromstring(urllib.urlopen(url).read())
```

Have you tried this?

Answer (score 0):

This works, but then again I do not know what website, if there is authentication required for it and thats why. You didn't give much detail about the website and what you tried in your question. This is an example of how you can save the html from a webpage:

```
import urllib

url = 'http://www.google.com'
lines = urllib.urlopen(url).readlines()

html = open('google.html', 'w')
for line in lines:
    html.write(line)
```